# MongoDB manage/check collections via terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm creating a basic fullstack REST app, using React and MongoDB.

In terminal, I am running 3 commands to run the server-side, client-side and database.

When I run my MongoDB database, I simply run `mongod` in terminal, which works and runs my database.

However, in terminal, I also want to be able to manage my DB.  For example, I want to be able to check databases, clear seeds, edit/add etc.

However, if I run `db` for example, to see my database, nothing happens. My terminal response is just blank and MongoDB continues to run.

How can I check my database in terminal?

Here is an example, of me running commands in the MongoDB terminal view:

```
➜  property-app mongod
2019-12-17T15:56:49.154+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=53117 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Reenas-MBP
2019-12-17T15:56:49.154+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.2
2019-12-17T15:56:49.154+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420
2019-12-17T15:56:49.154+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
2019-12-17T15:56:49.154+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2019-12-17T15:56:49.154+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-12-17T15:56:49.154+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-12-17T15:56:49.154+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-12-17T15:56:49.154+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-12-17T15:56:49.154+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-12-17T15:56:49.155+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2019-12-17T15:56:49.155+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-12-17T15:56:49.318+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1576598209:318795][53117:0x117a0c5c0], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 111/9216
2019-12-17T15:56:49.420+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1576598209:420387][53117:0x117a0c5c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 111 through 112
2019-12-17T15:56:49.488+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1576598209:488253][53117:0x117a0c5c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 112 through 112
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-12-17T15:56:49.729+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2019-12-17T15:56:49.801+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2019-12-17T15:56:49.802+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2019-12-17T15:56:50.114+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53883 #1 (1 connection now open)
db.myCollection     

db
```

Comment: `mongod` is the server; `mongo`is the client that lets you work with the databases.

Comment: As pointed out, connect to your server (mongod) via the client (mongo) ex: `mongo --port 27017` (if it is running locally). Then you'll be able to manage db, collections etc. `show dbs;` `use db;` `show colllections;` etc.

Comment: @ambianBeing - That is amazing, thank you so much! I knew I missed something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is connecting mongod to mongo, as:

`mongo --port 27017`

Comment: Just `mongo` is sufficient, in this case; the `port` `27017` and `host` `localhost` are default for a local installation and no port specified. You can specify those as [options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/index.html#options).